# SQL dump cut the result if space is inside the result

Tags: php, mysql

Hello I am using the following code to get result from the database , in the second dump te results is okay, in the first one there is a problem, because If file is uploaded with space in the name the result is cut after the space:

```
<?php echo "<a href=pdf/".$row['pdf'].">".$row['pdf']."</a>" ?>

first $row is = 124564
second $row is = 124564 SPRASHORT.pdf
```

how to fix the first result to be like the second one ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`href` should be inside quotes

```
<?php echo "<a href='pdf/".$row['pdf']."'>".$row['pdf']."</a>" ?>
```

OR

```
<?php echo "<a href=\"pdf/".$row['pdf']."\">".$row['pdf']."</a>" ?>
```

Comment: Ending semi-colons not required?

Comment: Nope, although I always use them but the last semi colon before a `?>` is not a must, hence I kept it as it is from the OP's answer because it was not an error

Answer (score 2):

If you have a space you should encode before linking

```
<?php echo '<a href="pdf/' . urlencode($row['pdf']) . '">' . $row['pdf'] . '</a>' ?>
```

Comment: Fixed the quotes. Thanks

Comment: in this variation it replaces the space with +